# Incompatible types. Required classname. Found int.

Tags: java, javabeans

I have this method in my class,

```
 public static AccountHolder getAccountHolder(String username, String password) {

        try {
            String verifyQuery = "SELECT COUNT(username) FROM accountholder WHERE username=? AND password=?)";
            connection = getConnection();
            ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(verifyQuery);

            ptmt.setString(4, username);
            ptmt.setString(5, password);

            ResultSet verified = ptmt.executeQuery();

            if (verified.next()) {
                // Only one Result
                if (verified.getInt(1) == 1) {
                    connection.close();
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    connection.close();
                    return null;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

I know I am supposed to return object of type AccountHolder which is a class. AccountHolder class code is as follows:

```
public class AccountHolder {
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private String address;
   private String phonenumber;

  // get & set methods();
}
```

I am supposed to return matching username & password from database using the method. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an approach that if a matching record is found against the input username and password then you return a concrete AccountHolder object otherwise null.

Try something like this, change the column names as per your schema:

public static AccountHolder getAccountHolder(String username, String password) {

```
    AccountHolder accountHolder = null;
    try {
        String verifyQuery = "SELECT * FROM accountholder WHERE username=? AND password=?)";
        connection = getConnection();
        ptmt = connection.prepareStatement(verifyQuery);

        ptmt.setString(1, username);
        ptmt.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet verified = ptmt.executeQuery();

        if (verified.next()) {
           accountHolder = new AccountHolder();
           accountHolder.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
           accountHolder.setLastName(rs.getString("LASTNAME"));
           accountHolder.setUsername(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
           accountHolder.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
           accountHolder.setAddress(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
           accountHolder.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("PHONENUMBER"));

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
                connection.close();
    }
    return accountHolder ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the element from the `ResultSet` that you get as an answer into an object of `AccountHolder` and return that instead of the line `return 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT USERNAME FROM accountholder 
                             WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?");
stmt.setString(1, username);
stmt.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    // valid credentials
} else {
    // invalid credentials
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change that prepared statement query like this

pm.setString(1,username);
pm.setString(2,password);

and

assign the setters like this
accountholder.setUserName(verified.getString(1));
accountholder.setpassword(verified.getString(2));


get those values in array or any collection for retrieval.
```